# Doxygen for jsp pages?

Tags: java, jsp, javadoc, doxygen

I need to document a (fairly) large project in java + jsp (1.0... don't get me start).

For the middle tier (all .java classes) I just used doxygen to generate .html and .pdf documents, but my chief asked me to document and integrate the documentation of .jsp pages.

AFAIK not doxygen nor javadoc are directly suitables for this job. Am I wrong?

The only way I can think is to insert `<%/** javadoc-style comments */%>` in the jsp pages, then compile the .jsp in .java files, then apply doxygen... but it's a bit over-intricated...

Comment: You suggestion looks like what I have to do to get Javascript documented with Doxygen :)

Answer (score 1):

JspDoc has been created just for that

jspDoc is able to browse a collection of jsp. The principle is very similar to JavaDoc, you add a comment section to each of your jsp like:

```
<% /**
<doc>
<name>directory2.jsp</name>
<category>System</category>
<summary>List all jsp files with category and summary</summary>
<history><date>10/08/01 us</date> Gilbert Brault 
<action> creation</action>
</history>
<history><date>10/25/01 us</date> Gilbert Brault 
<action> adapted pharos:foreach switch itCounter to Integer (was int before)</action>
</history>
<outline>
<ul>
<li>if refresh set or new session, list all jsp files of the server and parse them</li>
<li>List files according to the following criteria
<ul>
<li>creation order (item #) column</li>
<li>file name (no case sensitive)</li>
<li>category of processing</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</outline>
<todo>
<ul>
<li>display modification date and allow ordering by dates</li>
</ul>
</todo>
<copyright>Schneider-Electric 2001</copyright>
</doc>
*/
```

and your are able to browse this collection with three services:
- directory -> list all jsp with comments
- document -> provide a summary of the jsp structure, including the above documentation
- jspskelton: render the html and embedd the jsp as text

see: http://jspdoc.sourceforge.net/